# Problems passing in value to datepicker using Selenium via Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, datepicker

I am trying to pick a date in this website: https://www.myrealtrip.com/offers/21989

The code I have so far is:

```
option = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(" - incognito")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('https://www.myrealtrip.com/offers/21989')
calendar = browser.find_element_by_name('.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="calendarBtn"]/input')')
date = 2018-04-14, 토요일
calendar2.send_keys(date)
```

The last line gives an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state
```

When is it appropriate to use send_key?  `calendar2` is an object of type WebElement, and so I thought it might work.

Can someone help me? I've also tried clicking on the calendar and clicking on the specific date but found the layout very confusing.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select for instance 23 of april 2018 you can use this code:

```
driver.get('https://www.myrealtrip.com/offers/21989') 
driver.find_element_by_id('calendarBtn').click() 
days = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="ui-state-default"]')
days[12].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

send_keys won't work since the code on the backend wont allow..the option is disabled...look closely

"input type="text" class="datepicker noselect" name="choice_set[begin_at]" value="2018-04-10, 화요일" readonly="" disabled"

So its better to access the calender by the clicking on it like below..

browser.get('https://www.myrealtrip.com/offers/21989')
web_page.find_element_by_css_selector('#calendarBtn').click()
sleep(2)
web_page.find_element_by_css_selector('#dp1523344028627 > div > div > a.ui-datepicker-next.ui-corner-all').click()

then select whichever date you want by fetching the respective td

Comment: I'm afraid #dp1523344028627 is a dynamic id so your selector will not work.

Comment: @Frank Thanks didn't noticed that...i think we'll have to move through tags in such case..